# A name for semigroups in which left and right principal ideals coincide

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

Is there any standard name for semigroups $S$ in which $xS=Sx$ for all $x\in S$?

Examples of such semigroups are commutative semigroups and Clifford inverse semigroups.

Comment: I believe they are called duo

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Indeed there are some papers which use this terminology, but in Wikipedia paper (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_classes_of_semigroups) duo semigroups are absent.

Comment: The term comes from ring theory.  Wikipedia isn't very complete

Comment: The Wikipedia page would use the conjunction of left and right Clifford but to me Clifford means something else.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg For me also Clifford means something else, namely, to be the union of subgroups.

Comment: Yes that is what Clifford means to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People in factorization theory call a monoid $H$ *normalizing* if $aH = Ha$ for every $a \in H$; see, e.g.,

> A. Geroldinger, *Non-commutative Krull monoids: A divisor-theoretic approach and their arithmetic*, Osaka J. Math. 50 (2013), 503-539.

In the setting of rings, the term 'normalizing' is used, among others, by Goodearl and Warfield in [*An Introduction to Noncommutative Noetherian Rings*, LMS Student Texts 61, CUP, 2004], and by Jespers and Okniński in [*Noetherian Semigroup Algebras*, Algebra Appl. 7, Springer, 2007].

On the other hand, it is sensible to refer to the same objects as *duo monoids* (as also suggested by Benjamin Steinberg in a [comment to the OP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415718#comment-1066373)), in such a way that a unital ring is duo if and only if its multiplicative monoid is duo (a ring, with or without unity, is said to be *duo* if every left or right ideal is a two-sided ideal).

Duo rings have been studied (under this name) at least since the late 1950s. To my knowledge, they were first considered by E.H. Feller in

> *Properties of primary noncommutative rings*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 89 (1958), 79-91.

Since then, the term 'duo' has been regularly used in the literature, including by Thierrin [Canad. Math. Bull., 1960], Brungs [Pacific J. Math., 1975], Courter [Proc. AMS, 1982], Lam in Exercises 22.4A and 22.4B of [*A First Course in Noncommutative Rings*, GTM 131, Springer, 2001, 2nd ed.], Marks [J. Algebra, 2004], Yu [Glasgow Math. J., 2009], Cossu and T. [J. Algebra, 2023], etc.